# Show that the point spectrum is non empty.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

Let, $H$ be a non zero complex Hilbert Space. $U: H \rightarrow H$ be a compact self adjoint linear operator on $H$. Prove that the point spectrum contains atleast one point.

Things I know so far,

Let $ s = \underset{\Vert x \Vert = 1}{\inf}\langle Ux, x \rangle$ and $S = \underset{\Vert x  \Vert = 1}{\sup}\langle Ux, x \rangle$. Then we have spectrum is a proper subset of $[s, S]$. Further, $s,S \in \sigma(U)$.

I am not sure how to proceed with this information. I believe It can be shown that either $s$ or $S$ is in $\sigma_p(U)$.

Kindly help me out. Thanks !

Answer (score 2):

This depends a bit on what background information you have available. Here is one possible path:

- The spectrum is nonempty.
- If $\sigma(U)=\{0\}$, then $s=S=0$; this gives you $\langle Ux,x\rangle=0$ for all $x$, which forces $U=0$. Then $0$ is in the point spectrum.
- Otherwise, there exists $\lambda\in\sigma(U)\setminus \{0\}$.
- One shows that $U-\lambda I$ has closed range.
- Then one shows that $\ker(U-\lambda I)$ is nontrivial.

The arguments I know to prove the last two steps are not super complicated, but not trivial either.